# What's the best pattern when storing the value of an enum in a Firebase database via dart?

Tags: firebase, dart, enums

As far as I understand dart currently doesn't support values for enums like:

```
enum Person {
  Alice = 1,
  Bob = 2,
  Carol = 3
}
```

I want to store the data in a Firestore database with minimal space requirements. What's the best practice?

Comment: With pretty much all nosql type databases, the best solution is the one that meets the needs of your queries.  Strict optimizing for space might work against you.  Since we don't know how you intend to make use of this data, it's not really possible to say what's best.  There could be any number of factors to take into consideration, primarily driven by how the UI of your app needs to access the data.  It would also be helpful if you were more clear about which database you're using (FIrestore or Realtime Database).

Comment: The question is unclear - what would be the purpose of storing an enum in Firebase? An enum usually contains identifiers that behave as constants so, why store them in Firebase? If you want to really do that, it's just a Firestore document with a documentId of *Person* and then three fields Alice, Bob, Carol with integer values of 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

With Firestore, you may store this either as an array or an object, depending on the kind of treatment and indexing you expect to be able to use. I suppose array uses less space but we are talking bytes.

I use arrays to benefit from the "in" and "array-contains" [operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and objects for related data (references to other documents for example)

Comment: Can you clarify this answer? How would an enum type translate to an array? e.g let x = Person.Alice? Are you suggesting using the array indexes in some fashion? Also, You can't store a random `object` in Firestore - it must be one of the supported types. Perhaps you're suggesting something else but it's just not clear.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dart but your enum would be represented as an object in JSON (and so in Firestore).
`{
    [...]
        Person: {
         "Alice": 1,
        "Bob": 2,
        "Carol": 3
    }
}`